# Leaflet geojson search and zoom

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

Well I'm trying to combine 2 examples to search from my geojson file, and when selected it will zoom that property.

1. Search (search in GeoJSON one) http://labs.easyblog.it/maps/leaflet-search/examples/
2. Zoom part from here (without the dropdown) http://projects.bryanmcbride.com/leaflet/select_zoom.html

Basically the first one just with zoom from second. I have been able to get them working, but separately.

Codes (1.)

```
var featuresLayer = new L.GeoJSON(piirid, {
        style: function(f) {
            return {color: f.properties.color };
        }
    });

map.addLayer(featuresLayer);

var searchControl = new L.Control.Search({layer: featuresLayer, propertyName: 'L_AADRESS', circleLocation:false});

searchControl.on('search_locationfound', function(e) {


    e.layer.setStyle({fillColor: '#3f0', color: '#0f0'});


}).on('search_collapsed', function(e) {

    featuresLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {   //restore feature color
        featuresLayer.resetStyle(layer);
    }); 
});

map.addControl( searchControl );  //inizialize search control
```

Code 2.

```
// Loop through the geojson features and extract bbox and name, then add the options to the "zoom" select (no jQuery)
        /*var select = document.getElementById("zoom");
        select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('Select a State', 'Select a State');
        for (each in geojson._layers) {
            var bbox = geojson._layers[each].getBounds()._southWest.lat + "," + geojson._layers[each].getBounds()._southWest.lng + "," + geojson._layers[each].getBounds()._northEast.lat + "," + geojson._layers[each].getBounds()._northEast.lng;
            select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(geojson._layers[each].feature.properties.name, bbox);
        }*/

        // Loop through the geojson features and extract bbox and name, then add the options to the "zoom" select and build autocomplete(using jquery) 
        var options = '<option value="Select a State">Select a State</option>';
        var states = [];
        for (each in geojson._layers) {
            var L_AADRESS = geojson._layers[each].feature.properties.L_AADRESS;
            var swLat = geojson._layers[each].getBounds()._southWest.lat;
            var swLng = geojson._layers[each].getBounds()._southWest.lng;
            var neLat = geojson._layers[each].getBounds()._northEast.lat;
            var neLng = geojson._layers[each].getBounds()._northEast.lng;
            var bbox = swLat + "," + swLng + "," + neLat + "," + neLng;

            // Populate states array and build autocomplete
            states.push({label: L_AADRESS, value: L_AADRESS, swlat: swLat, swlng: swLng, nelat: neLat, nelng: neLng});
            $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
                source: states,
                minLength: 3,
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                    map.fitBounds([[ui.item.swlat, ui.item.swlng],[ui.item.nelat, ui.item.nelng]]);
                }
            });
            // Add states & bbox values to zoom select options
            options += '<option value="' + bbox + '">' + geojson._layers[each].feature.properties.L_AADRESS + '</option>';
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you just have to add:

```
map.fitBounds(e.layer.getBounds());
```

to the `search_locationfound` event function.
This will set the maximum zoom level that you can still see the whole layer.

So the `search_locationfound` event function from your first example would be:

```
searchControl.on('search_locationfound', function(e) {

    map.fitBounds(e.layer.getBounds());
    e.layer.setStyle({fillColor: '#3f0', color: '#0f0'});

});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/33wFx/)